# Oracle SQL select only these rows of 2 Tables that has no intersection

Tags: sql, oracle

Possibly it is a dummy question... but how to do the same in one select, without "MINUS"?

```
SELECT AAA, BBB FROM Table
MINUS 
SELECT t.AAA, t.BBB FROM Table t
INNER JOIN TableB b ON t.AAA = b.AAA
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: from the sound of your question it sounds like youre wanting to do a union, but the quality of the question is quite poor

Comment: I have to select rows in opposite way to INNER JOIN (exclude INNER JOIN rows)

Comment: @mallorn put the data in the question no the comment

Comment: Table:
AAA  BBB
1    Andy
2    Pandy
3  Gordon
4  Simon

Table B:

AAA CCC
1 NO
2 YES
4 MAYBE

Result:
3 Gordon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.AAA, t.BBB FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON t.AAA = b.AAA
WHERE b.AAA is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `not exists`.

```
select t.aaa, t.bbb 
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from tableb where aaa = t.aaa)
```